# How to run or use multiple registry mirror?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, dockerhub, docker-registry

I know how to run a registry mirror

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 \
    -e STANDALONE=false \
    -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io \
    -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io \
    registry
```

and how to use it

```
docker --registry-mirror=http://10.0.0.2:5000 -d
```

But how can I use multiple registry mirror.

This is what I need:

- Docker hub mirror
- [Google container registry](https://gcr.io) mirror for k8s
- Private registry

So I have to make tow registry mirror and a private registry.I want to `docker run registry` mirror 1st and 2nd registry, and one more `docker run registry` hold my private registry. The client will use three of these registry.

I have no clue of how to do this,I think this is a common use case, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PullSecret to tell Kubernetes what registry to get your containers from. Please see:

http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/images.md#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod